# Disable Sticky Keys, after pressing 5 times keycode 16 (SHIFT)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode == 16) {
    $('#click_me').css("background-color", "red");
  }
});

$(document).keyup(function() {
  $('#click_me').css("background-color", "#222");
});
```

```css
#click_me {
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  background: purple;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em;
}

#click_me:active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click_me">PRESS SHIFT 5 TIMES</button>
```

Is there a way to stop the "sticky keys" tab from appearing

when I press SHIFT more than 5 times?

I want to do it via javascript or jQuery and not from Accessibility=>Keyboard (Win 11).

I have tried =>  e.preventDefault(); and return but still doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Sticky keys and the listener that triggers it is outside the browser. There is no way to stop it from inside the browser/JavaScript.